# SQlite terribly slow vs postgres with ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, performance, sqlite, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

In my ASP.NET Core 2.0 RESTful API which uses entity framework core, I have a function to which repeated calls are made, with several at once. The function itself is a simple update, where it flips the value of a record from 0 to 1 and back again and saves changes.

During course of normal operation, the page may make about 10 queries at once. If I use SQlite, for some reason, all queries return at the same time about 1000ms (!) after the calls.

So I tried migrating to postgres and (shockingly), it can do the same amount of work in around 40-200 ms for each query.

AFAIK, SQlite is supposed to be faster, since the data store is really small anyway (~100kb). So why is there such a large discrepancy here?

**EDIT:** I've already read [this github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/5466), which says that all requests will be handled serially, so I/O blocking could be the playing factor, but I really can't see SQlite taking so much time for such a simple operation. The code I'm using:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> mark([FromRoute] int id)
{
    Foo foo = await _context.Foo.Where(m => m.id == id)
                                .Include(m => m.RelatedTable)
                                .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

    if (foo == null) return BadRequest();
    if (foo.relatedtable.Count > 0) return BadRequest("No related records");

    foo.bar = 1;

    _context.Update(foo);

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Content("success");
}
```

Comment: You are probably doing the transaction wrong. Show the code.

Comment: Most likely is due to I/O blocking.  SQLite is faster for certain uses, but you have to essentially start the database on each access, along with the promised atomicity of the database causes the transactions to work around database locks. Whereas postgres is always running and optimizes multiple queries, sometimes putting the operations into cache.

Comment: @CL. updated the question

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond I still really can't see it being so slow for a single update. One second for flipping one value sounds crazy.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite is a file-based database and relies mostly on the OS file cache. This means that it is likely to become slow if the OS reduces caching because files are, e.g., accessed by multiple clients over the network.

Anyway, most time is spent in the synchronization when committing a transaction. When doing multiple operations, you should always [wrap them into a single transaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456843.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Pure speculation here, but a few things come to mind:

1. SQLite doesn't support Async, so those calls are just adding extra overhead.
2. Npgsql caches the compiled/prepared SQL statements whereas Microsoft.Data.Sqlite has to recompile the SQL every time (issue [#5459](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/5459) would help here)
3. You might get better throughput by keeping the connection open between the query and update (call `_context.Database.OpenConnection()` before the query)
4. Turn on write-ahead logging (WAL) using `_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;")`